# regext for export some information from a string

Tags: php, regex

i have an output string like this

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.8-4:0.8.8-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Oct 22 2013 12:31:55 with gcc 4.6.3
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
[flv @ 0x23307a0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1000.00 (1000/1) -> 25.00 (25/1)
Input #0, flv, from '307263_191.flv':
  Metadata:
    metadatacreator : Yet Another Metadata Injector for FLV - Version 1.4
    hasKeyframes    : true
    hasVideo        : true
    hasAudio        : true
    hasMetadata     : true
    canSeekToEnd    : true
    datasize        : 42773717
    videosize       : 40350092
    audiosize       : 2403669
    lasttimestamp   : 107
    lastkeyframetimestamp: 107
    lastkeyframelocation: 42758866
  Duration: 00:01:47.18, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3186 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 1024x576, 3009 kb/s, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: adpcm_swf, 22050 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 176 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

i have to get some information like **duration , video bit rate audio bit rate and size of video and audio** from the string.
one way is do it with explode but the text before and after the important part of string isnt in my control and may change on each inputs

is there any way to match any key and value in the string by `:`

update:
i need these

```
videosize       : 40350092
audiosize       : 2403669
Duration: 00:01:47.18
```

and

```
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 1024x576, 3009 kb/s, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: adpcm_swf, 22050 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 176 kb/s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
preg_match_all('/(?:\b(?:duration|videosize|audiosize)\b\s*:[0-9:. ]+|stream #.*)/i', $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

See [`working demo`](https://eval.in/62594)

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => videosize       : 40350092
            [1] => audiosize       : 2403669
            [2] => Duration: 00:01:47.18
            [3] => Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 1024x576, 3009 kb/s, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
            [4] => Stream #0.1: Audio: adpcm_swf, 22050 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 176 kb/s
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (untested):

```
$duration     = preg_replace("#duration\s*:\s*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d+)#i", "$1", $input)
$datasize     = preg_replace("#datasize\s*:\s*(\d+)#i"                  , "$1", $input)
$audiobitrate = preg_replace("#audio\s*:.*,\s*(\d+)\s*kb/s#i"           , "$1", $input)
```

The same thing I did with "datasize" should work for every information you'd like to get, despite the ones having a different format (like duration and the stream info with the audio bitrate inside)

Comment: what do you get with these expression? nothing at all?

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/ {2,4}(.+?)\s?: (.+)/',$ffmegoutputstring,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

outputs...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>     metadatacreator : Yet Another Metadata Injector for FLV - Version 1.4
            [1] => metadatacreator
            [2] => Yet Another Metadata Injector for FLV - Version 1.4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>     hasKeyframes    : true
            [1] => hasKeyframes
            [2] => true
        )
```

Comment: Will fail on Duration (because multiple colons are on that line) and Stream information (same reason).

Comment: Yeah Just spotted that prior to your comment, slipped in {2,4} cheers

Comment: this is pretty close to my need but as i said icant moderate the start and of the string soat this time the element number [12] at the output array is the duration but how ever if the number change!? how can i get only the duration in output?!

Comment: Which exact parts do you want? Edit your question with your desired output.

Comment: I meant, highlight or put comments next to the items you want extracted inside your data.

Comment: thank you guys,
i found `http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/doc/api/ffmpeg_movie.php` it work better for me